# Preload stylesheet without executing it on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, responsive-design

Is there any way to preload a stylesheet without it being executed on the page so that it is stored in cache via javascript or jQuery?

I know that this is a strange request, but here is *why* I want to do this:

I have stylesheets for desktop, tablet, and phone. I want to load only the necessary rules for the device being used.

I know there is this option:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max-width: 960px) and (min-width: 481px)" href="tablet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max-width: 480px)" href="phone.css" />
```

However I also want to support IE8 and am already using JavaScript for manipulation of other elements on the page at various screen sizes, so am ok with a JS solution (will likely incorporate some of [Chris Coyier's jQuery solution](http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/)).

I want to have the CSS be cached so that if the user is on a desktop or has the ability to re-size the browser window to another device range they won't need to wait for the loading of the stylesheet at that breakpoint.

Whether or not a user can re-size the screen is already detected so I don't need a solution to this - **I just need to know if it is possible to cache css stylesheets with jQuery or JavaScript without actually effecting the page layout, and if so how?**

Thank you for your help

Comment: What if you add a classname to the `<html>` or `<body>` tags based on the browser width and rename all of your selectors to start with this classname?

Comment: @passatgt That's a pretty "brute-force" way of doing it, but not a bad idea at all

Comment: @passatgt that's actually what I was doing to solve this, but I need to also allow other people on our team to write rules, and don't want them to need to use that class with each rule. I am now looking into using an iframe or $().load to preload the css to cache but it seems a bit hacky... I would like to only use an approach like that if the css is not already cached...

Comment: Are you aware of respond.js, which will will allow older versions of IE to respond to media queries? Might be a better solution than what you are attempting: https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_css(url) {
    var ss = $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'text',
                url: url,
                async: false
              }).responseText;
    return ss;
}

function add_css(css, id) {
    $("head").append('<style id="'+id+'" type="text/css">'+css+'</style>');
}

var desktop = get_css('desktop_styles.css');
var mobile = get_css('mobile_styles.css');

// Determine breakpoint
add_css(desktop, 'desktop_styles');

// Determine breakpoint
add_css(mobile, 'mobile_styles');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this
Do this on the click event or when you want it to load in. For instance if your checking the device in jquery do this after you check it to specify which element should load.

```
$( "#header" ).child( "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"all and (max-width: 960px) and (min-width: 481px)\" href=\"tablet.css\" />" );
```

Comment: You can also use .append as well

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about trying an alternative method, such as media queries on your stylesheets.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 700px)' href='css/small.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 900px)' href='css/medium.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 901px)' href='css/large.css' />
```

*Source:* http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/